# MySQL blob to Netbeans JLabel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, blob, jlabel

I have a blob type field in my MySQL, I want to put the data in this field in `JLabel` as Icon. For example this `JLabel` will be user's Profile Picture in my form.

I used this codes but nothing happens
and also I want to `fix to width` or fix any image size in my jlabel

```
DefaultTableModel pic = MyDB.DataTable("SELECT `Picture` FROM `photo` WHERE `Employee ID` = 'EQ0103'");
     if (pic.getRowCount() > 0){
         Blob blob = pic.getBlob(1);
         byte[] image1 = blob.getBytes(1, ALLBITS);
         ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(image1);
         picture.setIcon(image);
         getContentPane().add(picture);
         setVisible(true);
     }
```

`picture` is the name of my jlabel

Comment: Debug each row in the code. Check how many rows you get, check whether 'blob' is null, check whether retrieved bytes are ok, check whether 'image'  is created (not null and width/height >0).

Comment: my `if (pic.getRow() == 1)` equals to 0

Comment: but my SQL statement is correct @StanislavL

Comment: yes @StanislavL now its ok but still i wont display

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got 
my filename should be like this

```
  txtPicPath.setText(file.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
```

and i used  these codes, and also it fits with the jlabel size

```
 ResultSet rst = MyDB.rsFetch("SELECT `Picture` FROM `photo` WHERE `Employee ID` = '"+ Data.User.getText()+"'");
         while (rst.next()) {
         Blob filenameBlob = rst.getBlob("Picture");
         byte[] content = filenameBlob.getBytes(1L,(int)filenameBlob.length());
         ImageIcon ik = new ImageIcon(content);
         Image img = ik.getImage();
         Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(Data.picture.getWidth(), Data.picture.getHeight(), java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
         ik = new ImageIcon(newimg);
         Data.picture.setIcon(ik);
         }
```

Answer (score 6):

**First : Return the Input stream from your database :**

```
String query = "SELECT `Picture` FROM `photo` WHERE `Employee ID` = 'EQ0103'";
stmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
```

**Returned image from Database**

```
BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(result.getBinaryStream(1));
```

**Then make rezise to this image :**

```
im =linearResizeBi(im, /*width*/, /*height*/);
```

**linearResizeBi** Method  :

```
static public BufferedImage linearResizeBi(BufferedImage origin, int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height ,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        float xScale = (float)width / origin.getWidth();
        float yScale = (float)height / origin.getHeight();
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(xScale,yScale);
        g.drawRenderedImage(origin,at);
        g.dispose();
        return resizedImage;
    }
```

**then  make the image is an Icon:**

`ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(im);`

**then add the Icon to The Jlabel :**

```
picture.setIcon(image);
getContentPane().add(picture);
setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [resultset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

```
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT `Picture` FROM `photo` WHERE `Employee ID` = 'EQ0103'");
```

You may change from

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob(1);
```

to another altenative of

```
InputStream binaryStream = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
```

You can refer to the official guide of getting image from a blog here 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/blob.html

Comment: no I must not use resultset cause I tried it and I always have user connection error cause I have here 100+ computers

Answer (score 0):

Blob has a getBinaryStream() which returns a stream of bytes containing the data stored in the blob.

ImageIcon, which implements Icon, has a constructor which takes a byte array as argument.

JLabel has a setIcon(Icon) method.

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ByteStreams.toByteArray(blob.getBinaryStream())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
picture.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ByteStreams.toByteArray(blob.getBinaryStream())));
```