# Save an image (profile picture) within a database as binary[] or string (url)?

Tags: database, string, image, web-applications, arrays

Save an image (profile picture) within a database as byte[] or string (url)?
What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely prefer URL instead of byte[].

The main reason is, not each language have same bit patterns while storing images to byte arrays. For example java's byte is signed (ranges -128 to 127) whereas C#'s byte is unsigned (ranges 0 to 255). This means, if you store the image in byte arrays using C#, the platform retransforming the byte array back to image has to be c# (unless you don`t want to deal with low level convertions)

On the other hand A URL is a URI that, in addition to identifying a web resource. As you can understand from the name its `Uniform Resource Locator` its platform independent. A user can use this info in any kind of platform.

Answer (score 0):

use  blob to save image files in data bases here is the code in java
 create table as

```
CREATE TABLE save_image (             
          id int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
          name varchar(25) default NULL,      
          city varchar(20) default NULL,      
          image blob,                         
          Phone varchar(15) default NULL,     
          PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)                   
              );
```

java file here to save image by user

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
class SaveImageToDatabase {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
// declare a connection by using Connection interface 
Connection connection = null;
/* Create string of connection url within specified format with machine 
name, port number and database name. Here machine name id localhost 
and database name is mahendra. */
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mahendra";
/*declare a resultSet that works as a table resulted by execute a specified 
sql query. */
ResultSet rs = null;
// Declare prepare statement.
PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
// declare FileInputStream object to store binary stream of given image.
FileInputStream fis;
try {
// Load JDBC driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
/* Create a connection by using getConnection() method that takes 
parameters of string type connection url, user name and password to 
connect to database. */
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");
// create a file object for image by specifying full path of image as  parameter         
File image = new File("C:/image.jpg");
/* prepareStatement() is used for create statement object that is 
used for sending sql statements to the specified database. */
psmnt = connection.prepareStatement
("insert into save_image(name, city, image, Phone) "+ "values(?,?,?,?)");
psmnt.setString(1,"SmashCode");
psmnt.setString(2,"GPU");
psmnt.setString(4,"127001");
fis = new FileInputStream(image);
psmnt.setBinaryStream(3, (InputStream)fis, (int)(image.length()));
/* executeUpdate() method execute specified sql query. Here this query 
insert data and image from specified address. */ 
int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
 if(s>0) {
System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
 }
 else {
 System.out.println("unsucessfull to upload image.");
  }
 }
 // catch if found any exception during rum time.
 catch (Exception ex) {
 System.out.println("Found some error : "+ex);
  }
  finally {
    // close all the connections.
      connection.close();
       psmnt.close();
       }
        }
         }
```

you can retrieve image you may refer this site here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426714/mysql-blob-to-netbeans-jlabel/15599684#15599684)

i used mostly code here hope my work makes you happy thumbs up my answer if you like